# Somebody who keeps asking why

Tags: word-request

Is there a noun which means a person who asks too many questions, especially *why* questions?

This person is surely curious, inquisitive. But I'd like to express the idea that this kind of inquisitiveness can be annoying.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335150/a-word-for-someone-asking-too-many-questions

Comment: @MichaelRybkin the link you have shared addresses the general issue. The question here is specifically (especially) concerning the "why?" questions. Maybe there is a word or phrase for this?

Comment: Certainly someone who keeps asking why should be called a "why"-ner? No?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for as it's likely to require explaining, but the Russian word *pochemuchka* (defined in a number of English dictionaries though not known to most speakers) means exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to express the idea that this kind of inquisitiveness can be annoying.

Here are some word choices:

- nosy or nosey
- prying
- meddlesome